# How to calculate the period of the movement from a potential?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, oscillators

I have an assignment, where I have an object moving in 1-D with a given mass  and energy, and the potential V(x), and I'm supposed to calculate the period of the movement as a function of the energy 
$$
V(x)=\begin{cases}\infty &x < -a \\
                  0      &-a < x < 0\\
                  \alpha x^2 & x>0
\end{cases}
$$

Should I find 3 Lagrangians for the 3 separate parts of the potential? And then how would I come to the period of the movement? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Little hint: The movement is periodic if your system has return points. Since the energy is conserved, an object with kinetic energy $T$ will transform all this energy when it "goes up" the potential, until $T=0$ and all the $E$ becomes potential. In this points, velocity is equal zero. You should be able to use this in order to calculate period. I've done this kind of problems in Hamiltonian formalism, but I'm  not sure how to attack them in Lagrangian. This may be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action-angle_coordinates

Comment: Break the problem down into the three regions. 1) What happens when a mass hits an infinite potential wall? 2) What happens when a mass moves in a constant potential? 3) What happens in a region with a quadratic potential?

Comment: Thank you @CuriousOne! 

So, starting from x=-a with a speed of v=sqrt(2*E/m), it would reach x=0 at t=a/v. Then it would go up until x=sqrt(E/alpha)... but how long this part would take?

Comment: Thanks @V_Programmer, I don't really need to do it in Lagrangian ... So with Hamiltonian, where it stops, H=V(x), and this should be equal with the energy that is a given here?

Comment: Using the Hamiltonian formalism, you have to calculate the Hamiltonian of your system. In this case it is the energy: $H=E=\frac{p_x^2}{2m}+V(x)$. Then, in the return points, $v_x=0\Rightarrow p_x=0$. This will give you two points, $x_1$ and $x_2$: these are the return points. Then, return to the Hamiltonian and write $p=p(E)$. After that, you have to compute $J=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{x_1} ^{x_2} p_x dx$. Finally, write $E=E(J)$ and compute $\omega = \frac{\partial E}{\partial J}$. I didn't write this as an answer since you've accepted other as correct, but I can expand this if you want =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, based on the comments above, that you have figured it out. Just for closure, I am writing the steps out.

If you had just a parabolic potential well, $V(x) = \alpha x^2$, you could get the period quite easily - for a given mass $m$, the frequency would be

$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{2\alpha}{m}}\\
T = \frac{2\pi}{\omega} = \pi \sqrt{\frac{2m}{\alpha}}$$

For half the parabola, the time from the bottom to the side and back will be half this:

$$T_1 = \frac12 T = \pi \sqrt{\frac{m}{2\alpha}}$$

The mass will slide along the bottom of the well with a constant velocity given by the energy (which is all kinetic at this point):

$$v = \sqrt{\frac{2E}{m}}$$

So the time taken to cover the distance $a$ (there and back) is

$$T_2 = \frac{2a}{v} = a\sqrt{\frac{2m}{E}}$$

When the mass gets to the infinite potential wall it will just turn around.

Summing these two times give you the period of the oscillation:

$$T = \pi \sqrt{\frac{m}{2\alpha}} + a\sqrt{\frac{2m}{E}}$$

As expected, one term depends on how steep the potential well is on one side, and the other term decreases as the energy goes up. And when the width of the well increases, the period increases as well.

Comment: I like this answer. Good reasoning, without using actions, only the fact that the potential is  $ax^2$ and a constant. However, this can be a bit limited (depending of the explicit form of $V(x)$). In any case, this is easy and clean. Good work!

Comment: @V_Programmer - thanks. I agree this is not a general answer but it is a specific answer to a specific question. "Make it as complicated as it needs to be, but no more...."

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the action integral as a function of energy 
$$
J(E) =  \oint p_x dx =  2\sqrt {2m} \int_{x_0(E)}^{x_1(E)} \sqrt {E-V(x)}dx
$$
where $x_0$ and $x_1$ are the turning points. (In your case: $x_0 = -a$ and $x_1 = \sqrt{E/\alpha}$). The Period is then  given by the derivative 
$$
T(E) =  dJ/dE
$$